# How to move Storefront theme footer widgets out of the footer row?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The Storefront theme footer.php file has an action which inserts the footer widgets AND the footer credit together. Here is the code section

```
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="col-full">

            <?php
            /**
             * Functions hooked in to storefront_footer action
             *
             * @hooked storefront_footer_widgets - 10
             * @hooked storefront_credit         - 20
             */
            do_action( 'storefront_footer' );
            ?>

        </div><!-- .col-full -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

I want to move the storefront_footer_widgets portion out of the container `<div class="col-full">` and insert it into a new container `<div class="new-row">` just above the other container. So the new structure would be like this:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="new-row">
            @hooked storefront_footer_widgets - 10
        </div>
        <div class="col-full">
            @hooked storefront_credit         - 20
        </div><!-- .col-full -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your active theme a `child theme` of Storefront?

Comment: Yes it is a child theme

Comment: It's very easy then. You just need to copy the `footer.php` from the main theme to your child theme (by keeping the footer structure) and modify its code accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the code above is what needs to be modified and I have no idea how to change this `do_action( 'storefront_footer' );` and make it output the the two separate pieces in  their own container div

Comment: I added an answer. Please try and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to split it like this. I didn't test but it should work.

First add these to your child theme's `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer1', 'storefront_footer_widgets', 10 );
add_action( 'storefront_footer2', 'storefront_credit', 10 );
```

Then you can call them in your custom `footer.php`

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="new-row">
  <?php
    do_action( 'storefront_footer1' );
  ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-full">
  <?php
    do_action( 'storefront_footer2' );
  ?>
  </div><!-- .col-full -->
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```